# Rotation Values getting mixed up C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I'm trying to use C# and Unity to create a simple game mechanic, which allows the player to turn `45` degrees right then set their new rotation to `-45`. It kind of works:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 215f;

    private bool isLeft = false;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            if (isLeft == false)
            {
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(90, 45,0);
                isLeft = true;
                Debug.Log("Turned Right");
            }
            else
            {

                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 0);

                // No matter what I put as the x value, it always sets it to the z, 
                // for example: if I put 
                // transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(90, 270, 0); 
                // the position would be 90, 0, 270.
                Debug.Log("Turned Left");
                isLeft = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's what I want to happen :

1st click: rotation values are set to `90,  45, 0`

2nd click: rotation values are set to `90, -45, 0`

Am I using a command wrong?

Comment: if you change this line :  `transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 0);`
for this one `transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(90, -45, 0);` should solve your problem

Comment: Thanks I feel stupid :p it worked :)

Comment: I posted as answer, please mark as correct :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you change this line : 
.   transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 0); for this one 
.   transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(90, -45, 0);
Should solve you problem.

Happy coding!